# What's Wrong with this Gradient-Computing Code?

Tags: python, derivative

I'm trying to calculate the gradient of a function at a specific point in two ways: Once by working out analytically what the gradient is and calculating that, and another with a f(x+h)-f(x)/h estimate. Then I can compare them and see which is more efficient.

I've written code for both. The code I've written for the first method I'm pretty sure works fine. Unfortunately, the code for the second method is producing the wrong answer.

```
def cost_gradient_theta1(t,m,x,y):
    c=cost(x,y,t,m)
    grad=[0]*240
    for i in range(240):
        t1=t
        t1[i]=t[i]+0.000001
        grad[i]=(cost(x,y,t1,m)-c)/0.000001
    return grad
```

In the above, cost is a function I defined previously, x and y are constants (actually lists of lists of 0s and 1s) and t and m are the variables I'm interested in differentiating with respect to. They're intended to represent lists of floats of length 240 each.

When I tested it out and compared it to the "real" answer, the 0th coordinate turned out fine. But from the 1st coordinate on, those partial derivatives are way wrong.

Do you see anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: `t1=t` does not *copy* `t`, so when you change `t1`, you also change `t`.

Comment: To add some clarity to @WarrenWeckesser's point after t1=t both t1 and t point to the same thing, change an element in one and you change it in the other. It is as if you are gradually walking away from the initial possition.